# Click handler still firing despite preventing propogation/bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following click handler for AJAX form submit buttons:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-ajax-form] [type="submit"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('submit form');
});
```

I also have the following click handler to "confirm" an action:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-confirm]', function (event) {
    if (!confirm($(this).data('confirm').length ? $(this).data('confirm') : 'Are you sure?')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML for said button:

```
<form method="POST" data-ajax-form>
    <button type="submit" data-confirm>DELETE</button>
</form>
```

My problem is that even if I click "cancel" in the confirmation dialog, the click handler for `[data-ajax-form] [type="submit"]` is still firing.

Is there any way I can stop this?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but the simplest way to stop it from trying to submit the form and act like a normal button is to change its type to "button" instead of "submit"

Comment: You are confusing the event callback with the event itself. Your callback is being called, but the native submit behavior of the form is being cancelled. Add `action="https://example.com"` to your `form` and you will see that it does not submit and redirect to that location. Event handlers will always fire, you can't cancel them. Event cancellation is about cancelling the native behavior that goes along with event being triggered.

Comment: `[data-ajax-form] [type="submit"]` and `[data-confirm]` designate the same element. So yes, both click handlers are executed. Simple answer is: You can't *«stop this»*.

Comment: Louys was correct, I ended up using the "submit" event for `[data-ajax-form] [type="submit"]` instead, and refactored the logic accordingly.

Comment: So your issue is resolved?

Comment: Yes, if you post the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I may be preferable that you answer yourself on that one... You can do it (if you didn't know) ;)